# How to check the condition before reading any method in the Controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, conditional-statements

How to check a condition before reading all the methods in a controller. After the condition is checked, if it is TRUE, then only the methods in the controller have to be accessible. If the condition returns false then it should be redirected to another controller. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can put your condition inside `public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
    }` on your controller, if it's true then it will give access to all functions in your controller.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example.

Comment: @Rosahn ,  This one is worked to me. public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }  But,It is working only based on session data.

Comment: You can use a hook or create your own controller and extend it to achieve this.

Comment: @ShubhamAzad , Yeah. It is also worked for me. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller automatically runs construct every time it is initialized, before it runs any other methods, so you can use it to set conditions required to access other controller methods.

Example:

```
class ExampleController extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct () {

       // use construct method of CI_Controller(the parent)
       // don't foget this because it wont work without it!
       parent::__construct();


       if(true) {
           //do the thing you want
       } else {
          // use the url helper to redirect to another page/controller
          $this->load->helper('url');
          redirect('another-page');
       }

   }

   public function index() {
      //display index page...   
   }
}
```